# How I can check for a valid date format in Perl?

Tags: perl, date, format

I am getting a date field from the database in one of my variables, at the moment I am using the following code to check if the date is in "yyyy-mm-dd" format

```
if ( $dat =~ /\d{3,}-\d\d-\d\d/ )
```

My question, is there a better way to accomplish this.

Many Thanks

Comment: If the source of these data is your database, why do you have to check the format? Just curious.

Comment: Better in what way? Are you worried about non-existing dates? Or do you want to allow for other date formats?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? People have supplied you with a few perfectly valid regexen for this. If you just want to check the format, these are basically fine. If you want to check the sanity of the date you need to do a bit more. If you want to actually check the validity of the date, even more.

Can we safely assume that the database is not storing this in a date field and the data might not be valid?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make sense to *validate* dates from the database, unless they were stored as strings--but why would that be the case?! If you want to take them apart, then it's a good idea to find which format your database puts them out in, and code a regex to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by others, if this is a date field from a database, it should be coming in a well-defined format, so you can use a simple regex, such as that given by toolkit.

But that has the disadvantage that it will accept invalid dates, such as 2009-02-30. Again, if you're handling dates that successfully made it into a date-typed field in a DB, you should be safe.

A more robust approach would be to use one of the many Date/Time modules from CPAN. Probably Date::Manip would be a good choice, and in particular check out the ParseDate() function.

http://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Manip

Comment: Time::Piece (in core since 5.10), has strptime, as does POSIX::strptime, Date::Manip (and DateTime) is a bit heavyweight for this task, and installing Date::Manip is a bit of a mess since 6.x went 5.10+ only, and 5.x versions were added to i.

Comment: Time::Piece does not check for stuff like 2009-02-30! eval { my $t = Time::Piece->strptime( '2009-02-30', "%Y-%m-%d" ); };

Answer (score 6):

The [OWASP Validation Regex Repository](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Validation_Regex_Repository)'s version of dates in US format with support for leap years:

> ^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(/|-|.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(/|-|.)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:0?2(/|-|.)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(/|-|.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$

The [Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=date) contains a simpler version along the lines of the other suggestions, which is translated to your problem:

```
^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
/\d{2}\d{2}?-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/
```

Answer (score 2):

\d could match number characters from other languages. And is YYY really a valid year? If it must be four digits, dash, two digits, dash, two digits, I'd prefer `/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/` or `/^[12][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/`. Be aware of space characters around the string you're matching.

Of course, this doesn't check the reasonableness of the characters that are there, except for the first character in the second example. If that's required, you'll do well to just pass it to a date parsing module and then check its output for logical results.

Answer (score 2):

The best and lightweight solution is using [Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date%3A%3ACalc)'s ***check_date*** sub routine, here's an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings
use Date::Calc qw[check_date];

## string in YYYY-MM-DD format, you can have any format
## you like, just parse it
my @dt_dob = unpack("A4xA2xA2",$str_dob_date);

unless(check_date(@dt_dob)) {
    warn "Oops! invalid date!";
}
```

I hope that was helpful :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can start with:

```
/\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30|31)/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would very strongly recommend AGAINST writing your own regular expression to do this.  Date/time parsing is simple, but there are some tricky aspects, and this is a problem that has been solved hundreds of times.  No need for you to design, write, and debug yet another solution.

If you want a regular expression, the best solution is probably to use my Regexp::Common::time plugin for the Regexp::Common module.  You can specify simple or complex, rigid or fuzzy date/time matching, and it has a very extensive test suite.

If you just want to parse specific date formats, you may be better off using one of the many parsing/formatting plugins for Dave Rolsky's excellent DateTime module.

If you want to validate the date/time values after you have matched them, I would suggest my Time::Normalize module.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a regex without outer check is much to complicated! I use a little sub to get it:

```perl
sub check_date {
    my $date_string = shift;

    # Check the string fromat and get year, month and day out of it.
    # Best to use a regex.
    return 0 unless $date_string =~ m/^(\d{4})-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;
    
    # 31. in a month with 30 days
    return 0 if ($3 >= 31 and ($2 == 4 or $2 == 6 or $2  == 9 or $2 == 11));
    # February 30. or 31.
    return 0 if ($3 >= 30 and $2 == 2);
    # February 29. in not a leap year.
    return 0 if ($2 == 2 and $3 == 29
                 and not ($1 % 4 == 0 and ($1 % 100 != 0 or $1 % 400 == 0)));
    
    # Date is valid
    return 1;
}
```

I got the idea (and most of the code) from [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html). There are other examples too.